# The "infelicities of language" means?

Tags: meaning

What does "the infelicities of language" mean ? Infelicities means "inappropriate and unpleasing manner or style".  So, is the phrase "infelicities of language" a euphemism for curse words ? Or is the phrase a euphemism for vulgar language ? Or does the phrase "the infelicities of language" mean something other than what I have suggested ?

Comment: I think you've got the right idea already.

Comment: A quick Google shows that the phrase has been used in a variety of  contexts with a variety of meanings. If you provide a specific context we can help you.

Comment: This has been addressed (as regards the stricter definition) on [LinguisticsSE](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/4555/whats-a-grammatical-infelicity) (see the most upvoted answers, and John Lawler's comment).

Comment: As Mitch says, it could be any of several things, depending on context.  To his list I'd add the difficulty of saying what you mean in many cases.

Comment: A student this past term, writing about the history of dating, noted that after one of the World Wars "a lot of males were rare." I commented, "You can say that there were not a lot of males, or that males were rare, but saying a lot of males were rare suggests that people were undercooking them. I gave up marking such careless errors and infelicities here because there were just too darned many of them."

Answer (score 1):

It can mean many things depending on context:

- awkward diction or phrasing, using words from different registers in the same sentence
- questionable grammar/semantics (not outright solecisms)
- blunt or jarring style (eg false parallelism or ambiguity from removing parallelism)

I wouldn't call vulgarities themselves infelicitous unless used in the middle of a poetic or formal discourse.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is used to refer to imprecise language, not adequately or clearly expressing a thought or idea, either due to the nature of language in general, or to ineptitude on the part of the speaker.  Here are some examples:

> Imperfect, too, in fairness - Rowling calibrated her prose carefully in "The Casual Vacancy", as if to show she could do it, but her old infelicities of language have returned. -- *The lady has a past*, quoted in [thefreedictionary.com](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/infelicities)
>
> Infelicities of language, whether in the spoken or written word, were identified and assailed by a great many people who seemed to believe that the English language itself was in a period of decline
>   -- [Language Topics: Essays in honour of Michael Halliday, Volume 2](https://books.google.com/books?id=IuPKNbG7kk8C&pg=PA66&lpg=PA66&dq=%22infelicities+of+language%22+definition&source=bl&ots=xHKKtp_JW3&sig=cZAOMb6bHtz3LDStX1ZUOYsVWNA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjNpZzJktrMAhUBTSYKHajgCpcQ6AEIKTAC#v=onepage&q=%22infelicities%20of%20language%22%20definition&f=false)
>
> Assuming that Dr. Hodge refers to what the general assembly meant, and not to any mere infelicities of language... -- [The Presbyterian Review, Volume 3](https://books.google.com/books?id=ZXXUAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA319&lpg=PA319&dq=%22infelicities+of+language%22+definition&source=bl&ots=4rKHMciZre&sig=-T-d3zSFnjTFAT8gERtPThzoAcg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjNpZzJktrMAhUBTSYKHajgCpcQ6AEILTAE#v=onepage&q=%22infelicities%20of%20language%22%20definition&f=false)